# Finding the fit $A\ T^a+B\ T^{-b}\ \rightarrow\ C\ T^c\exp{(\small{-\frac d T})}$ for an interval? (specifically in Mathematica)

Tags: approximation, mathematica

I'm given an expression

> $$A\ T^a+B\ T^{-b},$$
>   $$\text{with} \ \ \ \ A,B>0,\ \ \ \ a,b\in(0,1),$$

but the plus sign "$+$" is a problem for my purposes. I want to make a fit of the [following form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrhenius_equation):

> $$C\ T^c\exp{(\small{-\frac d T})}.$$

The approximation should take the closest values to the original function in an interval from $T_1$ to $T_2$, both positive. The term $A\ T^a$ clearly dominates the original expression for big $T$, as well as $C\ T^c$ when the exponential gets turned off. Regardless of that, the point is that I'd have an idea to do this in a neighborhood around a point, but here I'm convened with a whole interval, especially the values after $T_1$.

What is the general theory for this?

And specifically, I'd like to know how to do this in Mathematica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for Mathematica here is a variant with `NonlinearModelFit[]`. It uses several points (`n=50`) to approximate the required parameters in a given `model`:

```
A = 2; B = 3; a = 1/2; b = 1/3; T1 = 1; T2 = 20;
f[t_] = A t^a + B t^b;
n = 50; tb = Table[{k, f[k]}, {k, T1, T2, (T2 - T1)/n}];
model = C t^c Exp[-d/t];
g[t_] = model /. NonlinearModelFit[tb, model, {C, c, d}, t][[1, 2]]
```

gives for $g(t)$

```
4.8569 e^{0.0326438/t} t^{0.419195}.
```

Comment: Please note it's not necessary to dig into the structure of the `FittedModel` object.  It's cleaner and safer to do `g = NonlinearModelFit[tb, model, {C, c, d}, t]` to get an evaluatable function (try `g[2]`), or `Normal[g]` to get the expression itself.

Comment: This is really great, thank you. Do you maybe know or have some hint how one theoretically gets to this?

Comment: @Nick Kidman I don't know how it is done in Mathematica, but probably it is some variant of the non-linear least squares method http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-linear_least_squares